# Microsoft Test Manager - Test Automation

Tags: testing, tfs, automation, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have written a bunch of automated test scripts using visual studio 2013, and have categorized those in the hierarchy of Test Plan & Test suite using Microsoft Test Manager.

When I am executing a test suite, I am getting proper result whether a test case has failed or passed.

I can select a failed test case and create a bug in TFS project collection.

Is there any way which will automatically create the bugs for each failed test case instead of the tester creating the bug manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need to create bug manually. In TFS, there is no event associated with test run failed, so you can't determine when test run failed.